# Subgroup of class group

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory

Let $K/\mathbb Q$ be a finite Galois extension with Galois group $G$, ring of integers $\mathcal O_K$ and $\mathcal Cl(K)$ its ideals class group.
I want to show that $\mathcal Cl(K)^G$ is generated by the following classes:
$$[\prod_{\substack{\mathfrak m\in\mathrm{Max}(\mathcal O_K)\\\mathfrak m\mid p}}\mathfrak m]$$
where $p$ runs over the primes of $\mathbb N$ that are ramified in $K$.

Here is what I did. Obviously the reverse inclusion is trivial.
Let $I$ be an ideal of $\mathcal O_K$ and $[I]$ be its class in $\mathcal Cl(K)$.
Write its prime decomposition in maximal ideals of $\mathcal O_K$:
$$I=\mathfrak m_1^{n_1}\cdots\mathfrak m_s^{n_s}.$$
Since for every $\sigma\in G$, one has $\sigma([I])=[I]$ that means there exists $\alpha_\sigma\in K^*$ such that $\sigma(I)=\alpha_\sigma I$.

I know that $G$ acts transitively on the maximal ideals of $\mathcal O_K$ above the same prime $p\in\mathbb N$, but I do not know how to use this to conclude.

Any hint would be welcome

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The statement you are trying to prove is not true.

E.g. suppose that you take $K = \mathbb Q(\sqrt{34})$.

Then the ramified primes are principal:

- $6 + \sqrt{34}$ is an element of norm $2$
- $17 + 3\sqrt{34}$ is an element of norm $-17$.

In particular, they have trivial image in the class group.  On the other
hand, the group of $G$-invariants has order two.  (I think it is generated
by the class of an ideal of norm $3$.)

The fact that this is a counterexample is related to the fact that $-1$ 
is a norm from $K$ (e.g. it is the norm of $\dfrac{5 -\sqrt{34}}{3}$) but not a norm
from $\mathcal O_K$.

---

Your question in general is related to the *ambiguous class number formula*.
[This exercise sheet](http://math.uchicago.edu/~emerton/number-theory/number-theory.html) has more information on that topic (including the
theory for real quadratic fields, of which the above counterexample is a special case).

Comment: In your exercise sheet, what does the notation $X^{\sigma=1}$ mean for various $X$?

Comment: Also a naive question: is it known whether there are infinitely many number fields, e.g. real quadratic fields, with ambiguous class number 1?

Comment: @JohnM: Dear John, $X^{\sigma = 1}$ denotes the fixed set under $\sigma.$  If $p \equiv 1 \bmod 4$, then $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{p})$ has odd class number (see the exercise sheet), and so the only ambiguous class is the trivial class.  Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Show that conjugate primes of ${\cal O}_K$ have the same exponent in $I$'s prime factorization.

Hint: Galois actions can be applied to ideal divisibility relations, $A\mid B\iff \sigma A\mid \sigma B$.

> Regarding Galois actions and divisibility, if $A\mid B\Leftrightarrow\sigma A\mid\sigma B$ then $A\nmid B\Leftrightarrow\sigma A\nmid\sigma B$. Without loss of generality, $I$ is an integral ideal. Suppose $e$ is the exponent of a prime $\frak P$ in the prime factorization of $I$. This means ${\frak P}^e\mid I$ and ${\frak P}^{e+1}\nmid I$, which is equivalent to the same relations for $\sigma {\frak P}$, and thus $\sigma{\frak P}$ has the same exponent $e$ in $I$ 's factorization. Collect terms together in order to write $I$ as a product of powers of radicals ${\rm rad}(p{\cal O}_K)=\prod_{{\frak P}\mid p}{\frak P}$ (i.e. products of $G$-orbits).

Comment: That's my problem unfortunately

Comment: @joaopa I added a little extra.

Comment: Can you explain why $I$ divides $\sigma(I)$? My $\alpha_\sigma$ belongs to $K^*$, not $\mathcal O_K$.